# Remove duplicate elements off a multi-dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have an array contain this data

```
Array
    (
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 4
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
)
```

Now I want to remove duplicates from the ['age'] and leave the first one in tact.

So this would return

```
Array
    (
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [2] => 2
        ) 
)
```

Any ideas? Or is there a function already in place to do this?

Comment: If a value already exists in $array['age'] you want it removed and at the same time remove the entry with the same key (as the one that was removed) from $array['id'], right? That's kinda missing in the question body.

Comment: why is key '1' from 'id' missing in the return? the value of 10 wasn't a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Gordon said, you'd need a custom function to make the relationship but you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php ?

Wouldn't it be better to have the keys of the age array the corresponding values of the id array?

Comment: Brilliant idea, then i could just grab the first item and not worry about the dupes!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'id' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 10, 3 => 4),
    'age' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 2)
);  

array_walk($array, 'dupe_killer');

print_r($array);

function dupe_killer(&$value, $key)
{
    $value = array_unique($value);
}

?>
```

Comment: array_walk applies the user-defined function funcname to each element of the array $array. while it is not necessary here.

Comment: Doesn't work. Removes dupes from $ids, but doesn't then remove the same item from the $ages

Comment: array_unique() isn't recursive, how would you apply it to each element?

Comment: ah, i misunderstood the question. looks like an answer was found though, cheers!

Comment: @joshtronic. I think you need to read again the manual for array_unique();

Comment: @bakh actually, i needed to read the question, i was way off on the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
$array = array('id' => array(1,10,4), 'age'=>array(1,1,2));
$age_array = array();
foreach ($array['age'] as $key => $val) {
  if (in_array($val, $age_array))
    unset($array['id'][$key], $array['age'][$key]);
  $age_array[] = $val;
}
print_r($array);
```

this returns `Array ( [id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 4 ) [age] => Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 2 ) )`

Regards
Luke